# primero utilicen archivos de datos para generar el resultado, luego parte donde capturen y guarden esos datos y lean esos datos guardados y saque res

Tags: fortran

program indice_academico
implicit none
integer :: n
real :: indice
character(len=20) :: matricula, nombre
integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: creditos, notas
character(len=20), dimension(:), allocatable :: claves
integer :: i
print *, "Ingrese la matricula del estudiante:"
read *, matricula
print *, "Ingrese el nombre del estudiante:"
read *, nombre

```
print *, "Ingrese el numero de asignaturas:"
read *, n

allocate(creditos(n), notas(n), claves(n))

print *, "Ingrese las claves, los creditos y las notas de cada asignatura:"
do i = 1, n
    print *, "Asignatura ", i
    read *, claves(i), creditos(i), notas(i)
end do

indice = sum(creditos * notas) / sum(creditos)

print *, "Calculo del indice academico"
print *, "Matricula: ", matricula, "Nombre: ", nombre
print *, "No.   Clave      Cr       Notas"
do i = 1, n
    print '(I2, 5X, A10, 2X, I1, 2X, I8)', i, claves(i), creditos(i), notas(i)
end do
print *, "--------------------------------------------"
print *, "Íindice: ", indice
  pause
deallocate(creditos, notas, claves)
```

end program indice_academico